# Do I have to create a new SSL for additional apps in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl-certificate, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am starting to make more apps and finding it annoying going to my keychain to create a new SSL every time. Can I use the same SSL to create different apps?

I am also confused with SSLs and the certificate in the Developer Centre labeled my name and type iOS development. Are these the same things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a developer certificate (in order to create dev builds) and a distribution certificate (in order to distribute builds via app store). These two certificates are the same for all of your apps. You need separate certificates for each app for push notifications. Also each app should have its own provisioning profiles (again one for development and one for distribution) but this process is almost handled automatically by xcode in version 6 and above.

Comment: So to clarify, I can use the same developer certificate and not have to create a new SSL every time?

Comment: Thank you! I really needed the clarification!